# Как добавить кнопку "добавить в корзину" на странице результатов поиска Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить кнопку "добавить в корзину" на странице результатов поиска Битрикс? Используется компонент "стандартная страница поиска" (search.page)

Answer (score 1):

В выдаче у вас есть ID товара, а значит все просто.
Делаем кнопку "купить" для каждого товара в выдаче, при нажатии на которую идет ajax запрос к файлу-обработчику. В нем идет добавление товара в корзину по ID